# yellow and dying leaves of grape vine

Tags: diseases, grape-vine

Just wondering the possible reason why the grape vine leaves are dying. The fresh leaves looks fine, though a bit yellowish. Here is some pictures.
[image]

[image]

Any suggestions to cure the vine? Thanks.

Comment: What is the root growing in, and what is the water supply?

Comment: It is in a 24 inch deep raised bed soil. The watering is from below through sub irrigation system. Could it be the red blotch and rolling leaf disease caused by potassium deficiency or virus? I feed it with 10-10-10 about 1 month ago. The soil PH level is about 7.

Answer (score 1):

As you suggest it looks like a deficiency more than a disease or virus. Good clean new foliage and dying old foliage suggests the vine is stealing nutrients from the old to feed the new. If this is so, a broad spectrum treatment such as compost or rotted manure might be a better choice than NPK.

Check the quality of the incoming water for additives such as chlorine - ideally that sort of thing should be allowed to evaporate before coming in contact with roots but unless there is special provision for this a sub irrigation system can be problematic. Check [University of Maryland](https://extension.umd.edu/hgic/topics/chlorine-toxicity) for more info on chlorine and plants.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I treated it with 0:1:1 NPK nutrition solution and now all leaves turn to much more greener. There is no new yellow leaves appeared. Your guess is very accurate.